# Is there a way to update an Instagram description through their API?

Tags: instagram

I'm looking to update Instagram account descriptions on a 3rd party application. I wonder how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to alter the Instagram account description via the API.
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/